# animation like flipboard iPhone app

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to implement the animation same as appeared at the starting of flipboard iPhone app. I found couple of links for that:

https://github.com/mpospese/MPFoldTransition
https://github.com/Dillion/iOS-Flip-Transform
https://github.com/Reefaq/FlipView

But these all are for the simple view not with the gallery. Can anyone give me some idea that how to implement the flip animation with gallery?

Comment: At-list you have try that above link's code and change as par you project, You can't got same that you want so your posted link Github demo modify it and implement according to project.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried this https://github.com/mtabini/AFKPageFlipper

Provides following data source

**-numberOfPagesForPageFlipper: returns the number of pages to be displayed.**

**-viewForPage:inFlipper: returns the particular view to be displayed in the flipper for a given page number.**

Hope it helps